# nginx url rewrite (php with parameters)

Tags: nginx, php, rewrite

As the title states, I'm trying to redirect an url (php with params) to another page (also php with params). I'm running Nginx and I prefer solving my problem inside the Nginx site config file (no .htaccess). The server is running php-fpm.

I tried different ways but failed so far. If one of you could point out the solution for my problem I'd be really glad.

redirect:
https://my.domain/index.php?threads/a-first-post.12/

to:
https://my.domain/index.php?pages/welcome/

Comment: anyone here?? :D

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no `.htaccess` mechanism in nginx, all configuration is done in the main configuration file.

In nginx you cannot match query parameters in a `rewrite` rule.

You either need to handle those redirects in your PHP code, implement a LUA script to handle those or try to apply nginx `map` mechanism to get the redirects you want. However, your query arguments look complicated and I'm not sure if one can try to apply `map` to them.